# PHP: Can preg_match include unmatched groups?

Tags: php, preg-match

Can the [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function include groups it did not find in the matches array?

Here is the pattern I'm using:

> /^([0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)?\s?([^iIbB])?([iI])?([bB])?$/

What I'm trying to is parse an human readable size into bytes. This pattern fits my requirement, but only if I can retrieve matches in the absolute group order.

This can produce upto 5 match groups, which would result in a matches array with indices 0-5. However if the string does not match all groups, then the matches array may have, for example, group 5 actually at index 3.

What I'd like is the final match in that pattern (5) to always be at the same index of the matches array. Because multiple groups are optional it's very important that when reading the matches array we know which group in the expression got matched.

Example situation: The regex tester at [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) will show all 5 groups including those not matched always in the correct order. By enabling the "global" and "multi-line" flags and using the following text, you can hover over the blue matches for a good visual.

```
500.2 KiB
256M
700 Mb
1.2GiB
```

You'll notice that not all groups are always matched, however the group indexes are always in the correct order.

---

**Edit**: Yes I did already try this in PHP with the following:

```
$matches    = [];
$matchesC   = 0;
$matchesN   = 6;
if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?\s?([^iIbB])?([iI])?([bB])?$/", $size, $matches) || ($matchesC = count($matches)) < $matchesN) {
    print_r($matches);
    throw new \Exception(sprintf("Could not parse size string. (%d/%d)", $matchesC, $matchesN));
}
```

When `$size` is "256M" that `print_r($matches);` returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 256M
    [1] => 256
    [2] => 
    [3] => M
)
```

Groups 4 and 5 are missing.

Comment: Did you test that in PHP? See https://ideone.com/NSm7Iy, all the "empty" groups are there.

Comment: Yes. A print_r() of the matches array does not include non-matched groups, causing the index of matched groups to skew.

Comment: Yeah, it does not show the last items, [but they are there](https://ideone.com/3ondVH). All you need is to check if a group is  empty or not with `empty($m[n])`. Or is it a must that `print_r` should *print* the empty group values?

Comment: I guess that's just a bit of extra work to iterate to the expected array size and do an `array_key_exists()` to fill in empty values. Kidna expected `preg_match()` to do that out of the box.

Comment: There is one fun fact: the non-participating groups are just not initialized with an empty string value in PHP, so, Group 4 and 5 are *null* and you seem right, it is `preg_match` all to blame.

Answer (score 0):

The non-participating groups are just not initialized with an empty string value in PHP, so, Group 4 and 5 are *null* in case of `'256M'` string. It seems that `preg_match` discards those non-initialized values from the end of the array.

In your case, you can make your capturing groups non-optional, but the patterns inside optional.

```
$arr = array('500.2 KiB', '256M', '700 Mb', '1.2GiB');
foreach ($arr as $s) {
    if (preg_match('~^([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?\s?([^ib]?)(i?)(b?)$~i', $s, $m)) {
        print_r($m) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 500.2 KiB
    [1] => 500
    [2] => .2
    [3] => K
    [4] => i
    [5] => B
)
Array
(
    [0] => 256M
    [1] => 256
    [2] => 
    [3] => M
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 700 Mb
    [1] => 700
    [2] => 
    [3] => M
    [4] => 
    [5] => b
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1.2GiB
    [1] => 1
    [2] => .2
    [3] => G
    [4] => i
    [5] => B
)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/H4LVil).

Comment: I was sure I had already checked with a `var_dump()` for keys with a null value, oh well. Making the groups non-optional worked, but not by moving the `?`'s into the group. Instead I used this pattern: `/^([0-9]+)\.?([0-9]*)\s?([^iIbB]*)([iI]*)([bB]*)$/` -- Side note: I need this case-sensitive, because "m" and "M" have different meanings in IEC power factors.

Comment: Yeah, you made the patterns optional, just as I said. The `*` is also a quantifier that allows matching 0 occurrences of an atom. Note my regex **is** case insensitive - see **`~i`**. Also, I believe you could use `(?:\.?([0-9]+))?` instead of `\.?([0-9]*)`.

Comment: Quite odd that the `?` operator inside each group didn't work. (I expected it to.)

Comment: It does, see my demo.